# Full screen window in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I am using MFC to make a application. When I click that application, it must be show full screen. I follows that code

```
CRect rcDesktop;
rcDesktop.left = GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN);
rcDesktop.right = rcDesktop.left + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
rcDesktop.top = GetSystemMetrics(SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN);
rcDesktop.bottom = rcDesktop.top + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
MoveWindow(rcDesktop, FALSE);
```

However, it is only for multiple monitors. If I also have two monitor, but I want to display full screen application in one monitor. How to implement it. I follows that [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx) and I tried

```
CRect rcDesktop;
rcDesktop.left = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CVSCREEN);
rcDesktop.right = rcDesktop.left + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFULLSCREEN);
rcDesktop.top = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CVSCREEN);
rcDesktop.bottom = rcDesktop.top + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN);
MoveWindow(rcDesktop, FALSE);
```

However, it is does not work. Because I need put the coordinate for

```
rcDesktop.right = rcDesktop.left + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFULLSCREEN);
```

Could you help me fix my code. I am using visual studio 2012 and MFC

Comment: Reading [this Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145071(v=vs.85).aspx) should give you some clues.

Comment: I want to single display not multiple display. For the first code, it works well for multiple display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view class do the following:

```
SetParent(GetDesktopWindow());
CRect rect;
GetDesktopWindow()->GetWindowRect(&rect);
SetWindowPos(&wndTopMost,rect.left,rect.top,rect.right,rect.bottom,SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```